# Android : Reset audio

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I've some problem on implementing media player. I've no idea on how to reset the audio. What should I implement to make the audio stop and play again when play button is clicked. Please let me know. Thank you.

Here's the code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Button btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
Button btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.doa);

btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        sound.start(); 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Play Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});

btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sound.pause();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pause Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});

btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sound.reset();
        if (null!=sound){
            sound.stop();
            sound.reset();
            sound.release();
            sound=null;

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. You seem to be unclear about what `.stop()` does. It **stops** media playback. Maybe you want pause instead? If you want to play the file again, you'll need to load it again after invoking `stop()`.

Comment: @323go Is that so? What should I do if I want to play the audio back after the stop button is clicked? How can I load it back?

Comment: The same way you loaded it the first time ;)

Comment: See the [state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) -- you'll need to move back to `prepare()`. The documentation is your friend.

Comment: Still fresh and the diagram kind of confusing for me. But thank you, I'll try and get back to you @323go

Comment: @323go Should I add `prepare()` at the play button?

Comment: What would it take you to try it? Wouldn't that be faster than coming here and asking?

Comment: @323go I already try everything from my limited knowledge. That's why I'm asking and I think nothing is wrong with that :)

Answer (score 0):

When you stop the media, you need to prepare it again before you start it.

mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();

You can see the state diagram of MediaPlayer here at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: How should I prepared it? Do I need to add `mediaPlayer.prepare();` at the implementation of start?

Comment: you are calling mediaPlayer.stop(), that means you obviously want to play it from the starting. This is what you need to maintain in a flag. If the user clicks on stop, set the flag to true. Now, in your implementation of start, you need to check for that flag. If it is false, just play the media and if its true, then you need to prepare the media again.

Answer (score 0):

Media Recorder class does not support to pause and resume , see second link class overview try to use stop and restart..

In a new API level 24 it has given an methord for pause Link :       https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#pause()    On Resume Link :    https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#resume()

Try This code for stop :

```
if (null != sound) {
            sound.stop();
            sound.reset();
            sound.release();
            sound= null;
        }
```

Comment: `The final local variable vote cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`  I got this as the result.

Comment: @Mint Can you add code?? and where is vote variable you are using??

Comment: Updated the code. The error is retrieve from the `sound=null;` line

Comment: het @Mint now is it worked?? if your it run than upvote my ans.

Comment: It's not working, the error is still there @MayurPatel

Comment: I appreciate everyone help. Every answer is a point to me :) @323go